# Why do we use factory class to instantiate interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm currently reading book pro spring 6. I am a bit confused on one example from book

[image: Hello World Application]

Here is the main class:

```
public class HelloWorldDecoupledWithFactory {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MessageRenderer mr = MessageSupportFactory.getInstance().getMessageRenderer()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Service of type 'MessageRenderer' was not found!"));
        MessageProvider mp = MessageSupportFactory.getInstance().getMessageProvider()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Service of type 'MessageProvider' was not found!"));
        mr.setMessageProvider(mp);
        mr.render();
    }
}
```

The book mentions, that there is a small problem "changing the implementation of either the MessageRenderer or MessageProvider interface means a change to the code. To get around this we need to delegate the responsibility of retrieving the two implementation types and instantiating them to somebody else. The most manual one is to create a simple factory class, that reads the implementation class names from a properties file and instantiates them on behalf of the application"

I'm a bit confused on **changing the implementation of either the MessageRenderer or MessageProvider interface means a change to the code.**
For example, if we add an additional method to interface, the classes implement it will change. So what is purpose using Factory?

```
public class MessageSupportFactory {

    private static MessageSupportFactory instance;
    private Properties props;
    private MessageRenderer renderer;
    private MessageProvider provider;

    private MessageSupportFactory() {
        props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/msf.properties"));
            String rendererClass = props.getProperty("renderer.class");
            String providerClass = props.getProperty("provider.class");
            renderer = (MessageRenderer) Class.forName(rendererClass).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            provider = (MessageProvider) Class.forName(providerClass).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static {
        instance = new MessageSupportFactory();
    }

    public static MessageSupportFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Optional<MessageRenderer> getMessageRenderer() {
        return renderer != null?  Optional.of(renderer) : Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<MessageProvider> getMessageProvider() {
        return provider!= null?  Optional.of(provider) : Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: "changing the implementation" is not necessarily the same as "adding a method to the interface" - the *main idea* is that the interface stays a * constant*, but the implementation of it can be changed - for example, the `List` interface is implemented by `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`; with different characteristics (not the best example, since no factory method involved.) Maybe Log4J is a better example; the class used to implement the logger can be changed by simply adding the corresponding JAR to the classpath.

Comment: `HelloWorldDecoupledWithFactory` is the client, if it directly instantiates `MessageRenderer`, then changing the implementation means that the client has to change code due to the change being backwards incompatible, and this is a problem. With factory, even if implementation changes, you just update the factory, the client does not need to change anything - congrats, you just made a change in a backwards compatible way.

Comment: As the text states: we "delegate" the instantiation of the object to the Factory. Based on the parameters you pass, it knows what type of implementation you require, there's no need to repeat all of that business logic, nor is  there a need to clutter the rest of your code with it. Basically, a big part of the point of the Factory pattern

Comment: Unrelated note - you can simplify `return renderer != null?  Optional.of(renderer) : Optional.empty();` to `return Optional.ofNullable(renderer);`

Comment: The problem to be solved here is that you maybe want your program to run sometimes using a `StandardOutMessageRenderer` and sometimes using an `HTMLMessageRenderer`. If your main class directly creates a `new StandardOutMessageRenderer()` you need to recompile it if you want to use it with a `new HTMLMessageRenderer()`. When using the factory pattern you just need to change a property in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 classes that have `MessageRenderer` as an object and you have the following interface implementation:

```
public class MessageRendererImpl implements MessageRenderer {}


public class HelloWorldExample1 {

   private MessageRenderer render;

   public HelloWorldExample1() {
     render = new MessageRendererImpl();
   }
}

public class HelloWorldExample2 {

   private MessageRenderer render;

   public HelloWorldExample2() {
     render = new MessageRendererImpl();
   }
}
```

So in this case if you want to create another `MessageRenderer` implementation class `MessageRendererImplNew`, you should change the name in every class. So in the this case you the `Factory` class do the initiation by only reading the class name from the properties file, which you change from one place only.